# super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type in pandas

Tags: python, super

I am pulling the data from Sql in python using:

```
df_sql = pd.read_sql_query('select * from table', conn)
```

which was working fine till now. today when i was installing some other packages using pip install, my pandas got reinstalled/updated too.

```
pd.__version__
Out[8]: '0.22.0'
```

Now when i run the above code i get error:

```
  File "C:\xxx\xxx\xxxx\xx\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\dtypes.py", line 697, in is_dtype
    #        return super(IntervalDtype, cls).all()

TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

I even tried to fix this by following steps in the below mentioned link. still getting error

[super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43751455/supertype-obj-obj-must-be-an-instance-or-subtype-of-type][1])

Complete error:

```
df_sql = pd.read_sql_query('select * from table', conn)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-9-f26429b805cd>", line 1, in <module>
    df_sql = pd.read_sql_query('select * from table', conn)

  File "C:\xxx\xxxx\xxx\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 332, in read_sql_query
    parse_dates=parse_dates, chunksize=chunksize)

  File "C:\xxx\xxxx\xxx\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1458, in read_query
    parse_dates=parse_dates)

  File "C:\xxx\xxxx\xxx\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 157, in _wrap_result
    coerce_float=coerce_float)

  File "C:\xxx\xxxx\xxx\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1093, in from_records
    columns = _ensure_index(columns)

  File "C:\xxx\xxxx\xxx\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4212, in _ensure_index
    def _get_na_value(dtype):

  File "C:\xxx\xxxx\xxx\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 205, in __new__
    if is_interval_dtype(data):

  File "C:\xxx\xxxx\xxx\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\common.py", line 475, in is_interval_dtype
    return IntervalDtype.is_dtype(arr_or_dtype)

  File "C:\xxx\xxxx\xxx\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\dtypes.py", line 696, in is_dtype
    return super(IntervalDtype, cls).is_dtype(dtype)

TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

Comment: What output do you get if you run `import sys; print(sys.version)`?

Comment: Also, please post the full stack trace. Don't abridge it.

Comment: 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 10:22:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: I have added the complete error.

Comment: @aim replace `pd.read_sql_query` to `pd.read_sql`

Comment: @shaikmoeed getting same error

Comment: That stack trace should be impossible with a functioning copy of pandas. It looks like you might have corrupted pandas somehow. Shut down Python, uninstall pandas, and reinstall it.

Comment: its working now. i uninstall pandas, and reinstall it. thankyou