# Python - TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type?

Tags: python, api

I tried pynytimes Python wrapper package for New York Times API and using Requests and got the below errors.

Any idea what's wrong and how can I obtain queried results?

Thank you in advance!

**Attempt 1 - using requests**

```
import requests
url = 'https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?begin_date=20100101&end_date=20100201&q=Apple%20Inc&api-key=myNYTapiKeyXXXX'
articles = requests.get(url)
```

**Attempt 2 using Python wrapper package, pynytimes:**
https://github.com/michadenheijer/pynytimes

```
from pynytimes import NYTAPI
nytimes_apikey = "myapikeyxxxxx"
nyt = NYTAPI(nytimes_apikey)
top_stories = nyt.top_stories()
```

**Error message received in both instances:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-398-b09b87b0632b>", line 3, in <module>
    nyt = NYTAPI(nytimes_apikey)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pynytimes\api.py", line 194, in __init__
    self.session = requests.Session()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 417, in __init__
    self.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter())

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 123, in __init__
    super(HTTPAdapter, self).__init__()

TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

Comment: I'm getting results using your first attempt. What response code do you get back for that?

Comment: i didn't get response code as the code generated error as shown above

Comment: @YiWenEdwinAng do see my answer and let me know if it helps

Comment: Thanks guys for helping. I reinstalled lib requests via conda, restarted spyder and the issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a specific error on `Jupyter notebook`.

This error occurs when you reload the module with the class in a Jupiter notebook.

**Easy solution is to restart the kernel.**

Check out @Mike W's [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52927102/3851003) for more detail.

Comment: Thanks guys for helping. I reinstalled lib requests via conda, restarted spyder and the issue resolved

Answer (score 0):

Been encountering a similar issue in jupyter notebooks.

For me, the issue was because I was using [pdbpp](https://github.com/pdbpp/pdbpp) (version 0.10.3) alongside ipython, which was causing this issue. `pip uninstall pdbpp` fixed my problem and I stopped encountering `TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type` in my notebook.