# MLKNN __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, machine-learning, knn, multilabel-classification

hello I keep receiving this error need some help

```
from skmultilearn.adapt import MLkNN

classifier = MLkNN(k=20)

 classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

predictions = classifier.predict(X_test)

 accuracy_score(y_test,predictions);

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)<ipython-input-207-3038330bae31> in <module>()45 # train----> 6 classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)78 # predict

1 frames/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/skmultilearn/adapt/mlknn.py in compute_cond(self, X, y)163         """164--> 165         self.knn = NearestNeighbors(self.k).fit(X)166         c = sparse.lil_matrix((self._num_labels, self.k + 1), dtype='i8')167         cn = sparse.lil_matrix((self._num_labels, self.k + 1), dtype='i8')

TypeError: init() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I looked on google but I didn't find an answer

Comment: This is related to the version, find the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69734051/mlknn-int-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given-with-fit-method

Comment: i did tried but i still get the same issue

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74613688/typeerror-skmultilearn-error-with-multilabel-knn).
And the answer is to make a modification in the mlknn.py file itself.