# TypeError: skmultilearn error with Multilabel kNN

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to use multilabel kNN of skmultilearn package but I get an error that I can not resolve.

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_multilabel_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X, y = make_multilabel_classification(n_samples=700,
                                  n_features = 80,
                                  n_classes=5, 
                                  n_labels=2,
                                  allow_unlabeled=False,
                                  random_state=1)                                  
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)
from skmultilearn.adapt import MLkNN
classifier = MLkNN(k=3)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hiki/Documents/Uni/Practical_Work/test_scene.py", line 55, in <module>
    classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "/home/hiki/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mllearn/alg_adapt/mlknn.py", line 14, in fit
    self.knn = NearestNeighbors(self.k)
TypeError: NearestNeighbors.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I am doing exactly what the package advises me to do to run an experiment. Could someone please advise me further?

Comment: It's a bug, you need to open the "mlknn.py" file and replace `self.knn = NearestNeighbors(self.k)` with `self.knn = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=self.k)`.